# How to apply patch in OWB11gR2(Oracle Warehouse Builder)

Tags: oracle, etl, data-warehouse

I need to apply patch in the current oracle warehouse builder. My database version is oracle database 11gR2 and OWB version is also 11gR2.

Comment: Hi, and welcome. First, read the installation documentation for the patch. If you still have questions, read this document on how to ask a good question on this site: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the workaround

Step 1: Download required patch

Step 2: Extract and read readme file.

Step 3: Export the following variables

```
    export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1

    export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/perl/bin:$PATH

    export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch:$PATH
```

Step 4: Go to the patch folder and run the following command

```
    opatch apply
```